# PowerShell not setting property on SqlConnectionStringBuilder (works in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, sqlclient

I'm trying to run the below in PowerShell and getting the error 'Keyword not supported: 'DataSource''.

```
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

$builder = New-Object SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$builder.DataSource = "localhost"
```

Searching around, this error appears when you attempt to open a connection where the key is set to 'DataSource' rather than the correct 'Data Source'. But I'm not writing directly to the connection string, I'm simply trying to set the property on the [builder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

The thing is, when I run the equivalent in C#, it works fine:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "localhost";
```

I've checked the assembly with builder.GetType().Assembly.Location and they're both loading from the same assembly (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll), so why is PowerShell trying to write to the connection string rather than set the property? This issue occurs in both PowerShell 5.1 and 7

Comment: The builder still needs to eventually produce the an actual string.

Comment: You could do one of the following: `$builder = New-Object SqlConnectionStringBuilder -Property @{'DataSource'='localhost';}` or `$builder = New-Object SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source = localhost")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're encountering here is a conflict between PowerShell's dictionary adapter and the native .NET member adapter.

In short, the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class implements the `IDictionary` interface, which in turn causes PowerShell to attempt to treat property access (ie. `$builder.PropertyName`) as an indexing operation (ie. `$builder['PropertyName']`).

You can either use the underlying target key name:

```
$builder.'Data Source' = 'localhost'
# or 
$builder['Data Source'] = 'localhost'
```

... or you can bypass the dictionary adapter by interacting with the `psobject` memberset:

```
$builder.psobject.Properties['DataSource'].Value = 'localhost'
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like an indexing operation, but I couldn't see how that would be happening. Thanks for the lesson!